# Branch Points and Branch Cuts for cube root

Tags: branch-cuts, branch-points

Having trouble with finding the branch points/branch cuts of this function:

f(z)= $3\sqrt\frac{(z-2)(z+1)}{(z+2)}$

ive tried using the equation $z=re^{i\theta +2\pi n}$ but then I don't really know how to approach the question.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think i've found branch points at z= -2, -1, 2, but still don't know how to determine how to find the branch cut

Comment: The general rule is : "Assign branch cuts in the complex plane, such that:
• Every branch point has a branch cut ending on it.
• Every branch cut ends on a branch point.
Note that any branch point lying at infinity must also obey these rules. The branch cuts should not intersect." In your case we have a branch cuts at infinity, so you can cut with one segment between $-1, -2$ or one segment between $-1, 2$ and then a ray from the remaining point.

Comment: Anyway also a semicircle between $-2, 2$ and a ray from $-1$ is a good cut.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say, so i have the segments (2,infinity), (-1,2), (-1,-2), (-2,-infinity): how would i find discontinuity in these intervals by using the principle branch?

Comment: @N74 can you tell me how to determine the discontinuity between the 3 different thetas? - Really stuck on this